# Assassin's Creed Syndicate RAM issue?

Tags: assassins-creed-syndicate

I have just purchased Assassin's Creed Syndicate, and I have the right graphics card installed correctly, but it will not let me use more than 2 gigabytes of the 16 gigabytes I have installed. Is there a way to fix that?

I'm using an Nvidia GTX Geforce 1050 and have 16 GB RAM.

[image]

This is how much the game is letting me use:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the RAM in your system with the RAM of your GPU. Your computer itself has 16 GB of RAM that are used for general computing. Your 1050 has 2 GB of dedicated memory that's directly on the card and is exclusively used by your GPU. Note that there isn't even a 16 GB model of the 1050. 16 GB is an insane amount of RAM for a GPU, to the point that right now I am unaware of any consumer-grade GPUs with that amount of RAM (apart from maybe the Titan RTX, but that GPU costs so much it's hard to consider it consumer-grade).

Comment: is there a way i can add more?

Comment: @KieranKennett you could buy a new GPU, but I'll be honest with you: the current CPU that's in your computer is a VERY old budget model and you may end up replacing your GPU, only to run into performance issues from your CPU. It might be a better idea to replace your entire computer. I hope you didn't buy that GPU in hopes of having better game performance, because it's way too powerful for your current CPU and won't help much, if at all.

Comment: thank you, ill just keep it how it is and save for a better pc